# Trouble getting selected=selected to behave as expected when it's echo'd in php

Tags: php, select, selected

This code should echo selected=selected to the relevant options, but it's not showing the selected value as highlighted, or showing selected=selected in the source code.

```
<?php   
try {  
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_id = :user_id");  
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
$stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
$row = $stmt->fetch();
?>
<select name="gift_privacy">
<option value="Standard" <?php if($row['gift_privacy']=='Standard') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Standard</option>
<option value="Gift ID Req" <?php if($row['gift_privacy']=='Gift_ID_Req') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Require program ID</option>
<option value="Not Enrolled" <?php if($row['gift_privacy']=='Not_Enrolled') echo     </select>
```

*The result of `var_dump($row);`:*

```
["gift_privacy"]=> string(12) "Not Enrolled"
```

*The source code*

```
<select name="gift_privacy" style="width:12em;">
<option value="Standard" >Standard</option>
<option value="Gift ID Req" >Require program ID</option>
<option value="Not Enrolled" >Do not enroll</option>
</select>
```

Comment: look at the option value on the last one ... it goes straight from echo to </select>? did you copy and paste wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is:

```
if($row['gift_privacy']=='Not_Enrolled')
```

but your string is "Not Enrolled" (no underscore). Either change the condition and remove the underscore, or change the value you're returning to have an underscore.

Comment: That's embarrassing! Thanks for catching it :-) I'll accept your answer as soon as the system allows me to :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your if statement says `$row['gift_privacy']=='Not_Enrolled'`, whilst your var_dump output says `["gift_privacy"]=> string(12) "Not Enrolled"`. Please note the underscore (_) between Not and Enrolled.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for catching that :-) Unfortunately I can't do more than upvote your answer since I can only accept one answer